# websphere - wsadmin tool WAR deployment - META-INF/was.module (No such file or directory)

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, wsadmin

I am running the wsadmin tool remotely while trying to install WAR file getting below exception. In case of EAR deployment Install or update, It's Okay

com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: java.io.FileNotFoundException

/opt/WASClient/wstemp/appmgmt/wrap_171e9d69d31_1/META-INF/was.module (No such file or directory)

Any help, please

Comment: What version are WAS are you using?  What's the wsadmin command you're running?  You've installed the admin client on a machine other than the server and from that machine you're trying to install a WAR?

Comment: @FRowe   Version 8.5.5.15 - /opt/WASClient/wsadmin.sh - lang jython -user *** -password *** -conntype SOAP -host *** -port *** - f /opt/wasscript/installOrUpdateApp.py /home/devopsuser/.jenkins/UserReg/target/UserReg-2.0.20.war  /home/devopsuser/.jenkins/UserReg/src/main/deployment/application.conf    ---- Yes from other machine I am trying to install war file

Comment: What's in your py file?  Have you looked at the DD of the WAR to see if it has an inadvertent reference to was.module?

Comment: @FRowe Yes, I checked everything, even though I installed app from WAS Console manually it works fine. wsadmin tool is running as non-root user. What do you think it's trying to write something in wstemp/appmgmt directory https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PK45407

Comment: w/o seeing the contents of your py I'm limited in helping.  What are the perms of  /opt/WASClient/wstemp and appmgmt dirs?  If you 'touch' a file in /opt/WASClient/wstemp/appmgmt while logged in as the user from which you're running wsadmin command (not the -user one), what do you get?

Comment: @FRowe perms are -rw-r--r-- of wstemp, wsadmin gives me AppDeploymentException: java.io.FileNotFoundException